# metal data structure of MTLTexture array for coreML's custom layer

Tags: coreml

I'm confused about the MTLTexture array for CoreML's custom layers.
In my mlmodel, the input MTLTexture of the custom layer has 32 channels and the output has 8 channels.
The data type of MTLTexture is 16-bit floats, or half. So the  input texture_array consists of 8 slices and the output consists of 2 slices.

```
func encode(commandBuffer: MTLCommandBuffer, inputs: [MTLTexture], outputs: [MTLTexture]) throws {
    print(#function, inputs.count, outputs.count)
    if let encoder = commandBuffer.makeComputeCommandEncoder() {
        for i in 0..<inputs.count {
            encoder.setTexture(inputs[i], index: 0)
            encoder.setTexture(outputs[i], index: 1)
            encoder.dispatch(pipeline: psPipeline, texture: inputs[i])
            encoder.endEncoding()
        }
    }
}
```

In my compute kernel function

```
kernel void pixelshuffle(
    texture2d_array<half, access::read> inTexture [[texture(0)]],
    texture2d_array<half, access::write> outTexture [[texture(1)]],
    ushort3 gid [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{
    if (gid.x >= inTexture.get_width() || gid.y >= inTexture.get_height()
        || gid.z>=inTexture.get_array_size()){
        return;
    }
    const half4 src = half4(inTexture.read(gid.xy, gid.z));
    //do other things
}
)
```

If the input and output texture arrays are [C][H][W]，for gid=(0,0,0), which channels are src.rgba stored in, and what are the rgba coordinates in its channels?

is src.r [0][0][0], src.g[1][0][0], src.b [2][0][0], src.a [3][0][0] ?
or
is src.r [0][0][0], src.g[0][0][1], src.b [0][0][2], src.a [0][0][3] ?

And how can i get raw data for input texture in encode function and print it out ?

Comment: Custom layer of cormel has no commits, then I commit encoder buffer, but the result seems to be unstable and may be different every time，why？
    'code'commandBuffer.commit()
    commandBuffer.waitUntilCompleted()'code'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your compute kernel, `src` contains the RGBA values of a single pixel in the texture, and each value is a 16-bit float.

The texture's width corresponds to W, the texture's height is H, and the textures slices are C where each slice has 4 channels.

So the number of slices in the texture is equal to `C/4`, and `gid.z` goes from 0 to `floor((C + 3)/4)`.

(Although that also depends on what your `encoder.dispatch(pipeline:, texture:)` function does, since this does not appear to be a standard method on `MTLComputeCommandEncoder`.)

That means `src.r` is the first channel in the slice, `.g` is the second channel in the slice, `.b` is the third channel, and `.a` the fourth channel in the slice. The first slice has channels 0-3, the second has channels 4-7, and so on.

So your first guess is the correct one:

> src.r [0][0][0], src.g[1][0][0], src.b [2][0][0], src.a [3][0][0]

Also note that I wrote a blog post about custom kernels in Core ML that might be useful: http://machinethink.net/blog/coreml-custom-layers/

Comment: Thank you！    I use makeBuffer(length: , options: .storageModeShared) to get the texture values and the results like what you confirmed.